# hide mesh parts using mask texture

Tags: transparency, masking

I downloaded some 3d assets from synty store, this asset pack specifically: https://syntystore.com/products/polygon-nature-pack and i'm trying to get the trees to look like the example but i see the trees with black parts and I can't figure out how to use the mask texture to hide the black parts. any help is appreciated

[image]

how nodes are set up:
[image]

and this is what the texture files look like in file explorer:
[image]

---

updated node setup:
[image]
and how it looks
[image]

Comment: You have set Metallic and Specular to 1. Is that intentional? Ok, no. I just read that you want it to look like the example. Set them back to 0 and 0.5 The mask is probably for transparency. You need to plug it in the Alpha slot of the Principled BSDF and set in the material panel Settings -> Blend Mode to Alpha Blend when you are in Eeevee.

Comment: i did that and still seeing the same thing. how do i know eevee mode?

Comment: updated my question with how the nodes are set up now and what i'm seeing @Blunder

Comment: [Check the render engine for Eevee](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15681/how-to-set-render-engine-in-blender) and see this for
[Blend mode settings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157071/blender-2-8-eevee-cant-find-material-blend-mode-option). Ok, I see that you solved it already :-) Eevee has a Bloom option in the render settings. The sample images seem to have made use of this.

Comment: cool thanks for the help and the links! i'm still learning all this so its very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

turns out i needed to use the alpha of the main texture (not the mask texture) to the alpha of the principled BSDF. I think the suggestion from @blunder to use alpha mix also helped (but i had to use alpha clip)