# Having trouble with alpha hashed setting

Tags: particles, transparency, hair

(I'm very new to blender, so sorry if I'm not explaining this with the proper terms)

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXuReln3XD0) to create stylized hair in blender, but have found myself stuck. Below is how my shader editor looks currently:

[image]

The tutorial I'm following's shader editor looks like this:

[image]

However, I cannot for the life of me get the tips of the hair strands to be transparent, as shown in the image below:

[image]

Instead, when adjusting the colorramp whose setting is set to "ease", I just get this result (despite having set the material to alpha hashed..):

[image]

Any help on how to get the intended result would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The tutorial is doing a couple Janky things, such as feeding a color directly into a shader mixer to use it for emission, and and if you play spot the difference with their shader editor and yours, you’ll see some missing/mixed up connections. If no one else does, I’ll give an answer on how to get the desired results later. This is more of just a diagnosis.

Comment: That's really helpful to know thank you! I'll triple check the connections!

Comment: If you use EEVEE you have to setup the Blend mode in the material properties panel. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157071/blender-2-8-eevee-cant-find-material-blend-mode-option

Comment: @FFeller I set the blend mode as alpha hashed!

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this, does anyone have any ideas? @TheLabCat